# colspane all columns of clone row

Tags: jquery

I want to merge all columns `(colspan)` in a new row which is created using `clone()` method of jquery . one more thing which i want that new row which have only one column after `colspan` should have all values of original row separated with space .

I have tried something like this for `clone` and its working for me as far consider about `cloning`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log($('table tbody tr').eq(0).html());
 var newtr=$('table tbody tr').eq(0).clone();
 console.log(newtr.html());
});
```

but no idea how to `colspan` all columns with value of original row comma separated.

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/3p3m2/1/)

**EDITED**

current html is like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Month</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Rahul</td>
            <td>#1</td>
            <td>January</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yunus</td>
            <td>#2</td>
            <td>April</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nitin</td>
            <td>#3</td>
            <td>March</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and after jquery code run i want to my resulted html look like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Month</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Rahul</td>
            <td>#1</td>
            <td>January</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yunus</td>
            <td>#2</td>
            <td>April</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nitin</td>
            <td>#3</td>
            <td>March</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Rahul #1 January</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("table tbody tr:eq(0)").each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).clone(),
        $td = $("td", $tr);

    $td.filter(":gt(0)")
       .remove()
       .end()
       .attr("colspan", $td.length)
       .html($td.map(function() {
           return this.innerHTML;
       }).get().join(" "));

    $tr.appendTo($(this).closest("tbody"));
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/uAwnQ/2/

Comment: @Karna Thanks. That's how I understood what the OP wants to get.

Comment: question edited to show what exactly i wanted, I have used first row as example for clone but it can be change.

Comment: @rahularyansharma How about now? If you need all lines to be added, remove `:eq(0)` from the selector.

Answer (score 1):

I should have done something like this:

```
var $tr = $("table tbody tr:first").clone(),
$td = $("td", $tr);

var content = '';
$td.each(function(){content+=$(this).html()+' ';});
content = '<td colspan="'+$td.length+'">'+content+'</td>';
$tr.html(content);

$tr.appendTo("table tbody");
```

You can juste change the **:first** selector to **eq()** if another row is needed.
You can either use a **.each()** if multiple you want to affect multiple rows

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/f932M/1/